# OCPP: Charing Station Connection URL

Tags: ws, ocpp

How to connect a charging station to OCPP server?

Can't seem to find any examples or docs about how it obtains a connection URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Charging Station provide a way to modify their Settings before the usage. For example, [Phoenix Chargers](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/us?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=1018702&library=usen&tab=1) provide manual in which OCPP connection URL is set as in picture below:

[image: OCPP Configuration Phoenix Charger Settings]

As you can see, the inputs provide you the way to set (*in order*):

1. WS(HTTP) or WSS(HTTPS) WebSocket connection
2. IP or Domain
3. Port Number
4. Endpoint

So the connection URL for this Charging Station would be `ws://172.16.112.9:8080/ocpp/` but you can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Can you please help me to find request body to send for each operations initiated by charging point?

Answer (score -1):

Every Charge Point work as client and the Central Station is the Server.
So, every Charge Point need to know the endpoint of Server.

Which version of OCPP you want use or server use,
I recommend 1.6 Json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30667481)